# Tikz plot 3D with a limit to infinity

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to plot a 3D representation of the cone for the semi-definite positive 2 by 2 matrices. But the asymptotic behaviour of the plot made me cap the value of z (restrict z command). However, restricting the value of z displays a plane at z=1 intersecting the plot. And if I don't restrict the value of z, the infinity limit triggers a strange behaviour...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=-1:1]{(y^2)/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code I have used with the restriction in z. How could I get the same plot without plotting the plane intersecting at z=1? Also, feel free if you have any idea that would make this plot clearer and neater.

Thank you.

Romain[image]

Comment: Restrict z to a value HIGHER than zmax.  I would use 2*zmax.  You want to interpolate the visible edges

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not show that the plot is a parabola when restricted to the plane z=1

Comment: Ah, they are cropping the axis, not the data.

Comment: So you're trying to capture the behaviour at the intersection while not showing the intersection? You could try removing the datapoints of zmax and draw the proper intersection as a function at the zmax level. So, do another \addplot at z=zmax

Comment: Ideally, I would like the plot to be contained within the cube x=0..1, y =-1..1, z=0..1, so the intersection would appear without the need to add any extra plot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet another parametrization.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                unbounded coords=jump,
                x filter/.expression={x>1  ? nan : x},
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]
({y/x},{sqrt(y)},{x});
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]
({y/x},{-sqrt(y)},{x});
\draw [draw=black!50, samples=25] plot[variable=\x, domain=-1:1]
({1},{\x},{\x*\x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could work with filters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                unbounded coords=jump,
                z filter/.expression={z>1  ? nan : z},
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=-1:1]{(y^2)/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Results look better if you change the parametrization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                unbounded coords=jump,
                z filter/.expression={z>1  ? nan : z},
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]
({x},{sqrt(y)},{(y)/x});
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]
({x},{-sqrt(y)},{(y)/x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                unbounded coords=jump,
                z filter/.expression={z>1  ? nan : z},
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]
({x},{sqrt(y)},{(y)/x});
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, samples=25, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]
({x},{-sqrt(y)},{(y)/x});
\addplot3[draw=black!50,domain=-1:1] ({x^2},{x},1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like an option, although it removes more elements than needed, like for instance the front of the cone is not displayed anymore. The best option might be to compute points offline and plot only the right ones!

Comment: @RockyRock You do not necessarily have to resort to external programs, you may just change the parametrization. I'm sure that there are even better choices. Anyway, I posted an example.

Comment: +1 Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have added a little tweak to the code presented above in order to remove the straight line (x=1,y=t,z=1 (parameter t)). The graph generated by the code below is exactly what I was looking for.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=0.75*\textwidth,
                axis lines=left,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
                zlabel=$z$,
                zmin=0,
                zmax=1,
                ticks=none,
                view={240}{20},
                unbounded coords=jump,
                z filter/.expression={z>1 ? nan : z},
                restrict z to domain*=0:1]
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, line width=0.25pt, samples=30, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]({x},{sqrt(y)},{y/x});
\addplot3[mesh, draw=black!50, line width=0.25pt, samples=30, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1]({x},{-sqrt(y)},{y/x});
\addplot3[variable=t, mesh, draw=black!50, domain=-1:1] ({t^2},{t},1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Romain

Comment: Better include this in your question as a final solution.

Comment: And consider accepting the provided answer.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `parameter t` or the like, but this is triggered by mesh. Just put `\addplot3[mesh,draw=black!50,domain=-1:1] ({x^2},{x},1);` in my last example. (Yes, it is somewhat strange.)